# Specifying number of engines with IPython ssh profile for ipcluster

Tags: ssh, ipython

I am working on using `ipcluster` from `IPython`. I can get it running, but it doesn't seem to be starting the engines on the remote nodes. I know if I am running engines only on one machine I can simply pass the `--np=x` option to the command line of ipcluster to get the number of engines. Do I need to do the same if my `ssh` cluster is using multiple machines?

Answer (score 0):

the SSHEngineSetLauncher uses its own `engines` dict, rather than ipcluster's `-n` option to determine how many engines to start.  So if in your config you have:

```
c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engines = {
    'host1' : 4,
    'host2' : 2,
    # ...
}
```

Then 4 engines will be started on host1, 2 on host2, etc.